# analytical approximation of the solution of a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, greens-function

Is there any method to obtain an analytical approximation (probably through a composition of exponential functions) of the solution of a differential equation?? In other words, is is possible to obtain an approximate Green's function of the PDE?

the equation in question:

$$\nabla ^ 2 \phi(\mathbf{x}) = M \frac {\phi(\mathbf{x}) }{\phi(\mathbf{x}) + C}$$

Where M and C are bounded constants of the same order as $\phi$. Additionally $\phi$ is bounded between 0 and 1.
The equation is subject to Dirichlet boundary conditions (although that is not really relevant. Could be Neuman or Robin)

Given the non-linear term on the right hand side, the equation does not have an analytical solution (to my knowledge). The obtention of the solution through finite differences (or other numerical methods that do not provide a function as the solution) should be avoided since the goal is to obtain a function of $\mathbf{x}$ that approximates the solution.

My idea is to find a method similar to how the polinomial expansion of Taylor approximates a function around a point. But for the solution of the PDE.

Comment: I suppose that in the large $C$ limit you could try a perturbation expansion $\phi=\phi_0 +{1\over C}\phi_1 \cdots$

Comment: As pointed out by @user619894, do you have any information on $M$ or $C$? Are they small or large?

Comment: They are both of the same order as $\phi$. In fact $\phi$ represents the concentration of  a specific solute, therefore it is bounded between 0 and 1. C will be close to 0.5 and M will be anywhere between 0 and 1. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Is the domain of any nice geometry?

Comment: In any case there are numerous numerical methods that provide a function at each point, for example finite element methods. You can also use finite differences and then perform low-order interpolation of the result you get, which is a kind of "poor man's finite element method".

Comment: Finite elements, finite volumes, and finite differences are not what I am searching for. The goal is to include this in a FV code. Particularly I am searching the Green function of the equation, numerical methods do not provide me a function that I can propagate through the domain, just the solution at certain points.

Comment: Green functions don't work the same way in the context of nonlinear problems; they basically just transform nonlinear differential equations into nonlinear integral equations, by "solving the linear part" of the differential equation. Also you are absolutely mistaken about finite elements and finite volumes, these provide the approximate solution in the form of a function that is defined at each point and smooth at most points.

Comment: I don't know if it helps but maybe you could use $d/dx \log(1/C+\phi(x)) = \frac{\phi'(x)}{1/C+\phi(x)} = \frac{\phi'(x)}{\phi(x)} \cdot \frac{\phi(x)}{1/C+\phi(x)}$ where first factor is $d/dx\log(\phi(x))$. Maybe a logarithmic substitution could help.

Comment: @mathreadler Since this is in multiple dimensions, that probably doesn't help unless the boundary conditions are extremely symmetric. Unless you can manage to represent $\nabla^2 \phi(\mathbf{x})$ in a nice way in terms of derivatives of $\log(\phi+C)$.

Comment: @Ian yes, it only holds for each partial derivative separately.

Comment: If you cannot assume that $\phi$ is small, maybe you can at least assume that it is close to its average value and expand around that. In any case, linearizing will give you some insight, and analysing the next order will be instructive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outline of a numerical approach you can try.

You can search for a power series representation in combination with the convolution theorem of Fourier analysis.

Rewrite like this
$$\nabla^2 \phi({\bf x}) \cdot (\phi({\bf x}) + C) = M \phi({\bf x})$$

1. Right hand side is M times power series representation of $\phi$.
2. Left hand side left factor is a set of linear combinations of coefficients for this. This can be easily realized as each monomial term of a multidimensional polynomial differentiates to another. Very sparsely.
3. Left hand side right factor is just +C on the constant term.

Now the multiplication of power series corresponds to a multidimensional convolution of coefficients. Here is where the multidimensional Fourier transform comes into play. We Fourier transform $\nabla^2 \phi({\bf x})$ and $(\phi({\bf x})+C)$ separately and multiply each coefficient. This should equal the fourier transform of $M\phi(\bf {x})$